# How does Django QuerySet cache work from get() method

Tags: django, django-models

I understand that query sets are cacheable and they get evaluated (DB gets hit) when the data set is first iterated on. But what happens with the `get()` method (ex: `MyModel.objects.get(id=1)`)? When does the DB get hit and when do we use a cached result?

I am specifically interested in a flow with an API GET request (if that makes a difference). If I have several `MyModel.objects.get(id=1` calls within the request lifecycle, will I be hitting the DB every time I call that `get()` or will I be using cached results?